# Parse page with different encoding

Tags: php, encoding, html-parsing

I made a parser for wordpress but since wp and db are using utf-8 and some pages are in different encoding, when I parse them I get gibrish.
I use curl to get content from outside urls and some match and replace with regex.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

I used the suggestion from Joni below and it solved my problem. Some sample code I used for future queries on this problem:

```
preg_match("/charset=(.*?)(\n|'|\"|>)/ism", $content, $charset);
$content = preg_replace('/^HTTP+[^<]+</', '<', $content);
$charset = @trim($charset[1]);
if (preg_match("~(windows-1251|1251)~i", $charset)) return 'Windows-1251'; 
elseif (preg_match("~iso-8859-7~i", $charset))  return 'ISO-8859-7';
elseif (preg_match("~(koi8|iso-ir-111)~i", $charset))  return 'KOI8-R';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detect the correct encoding from the content type header (or HTML meta tag if the header is missing) and use it when you parse the document.

Comment: I used your suggestion and it worked great. I parsed the header first and then the content. So simple thanks!